# django constance localize language

Tags: django, localization, django-constance

I use django-constance

```
CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
    'MESSAGE_ROSETTE_DISCONNECT': ('Device {device_name} disconnected from the rosette',
                                   'Message that device disconnection from the rosette'),
    'MESSAGE_ROSETTE_CONNECT': ('Device {device_name} connected to the rosette',
                                'Message that device connection to the rosette'),
...
}
```

I want set the different text for different languages. Is it possible? Something like this

```
CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
    'MESSAGE_ROSETTE_DISCONNECT': {
     'en': ('Device {device_name} disconnected from the rosette', 'Message that device disconnection from the rosette'),
     'it': ('Same about {device_name} in Italian language',
     'Italian text'),
    }
...
}
```

What is the best way to implement it? And how to call the constanse? Now its like this:

```
text = config.MESSAGE_BATTERY_LEVEL.format(device_name=self.device.name)
```